# Split array into pieces and add every next two items in a new array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array, like:

```
$list = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e',
              'f', '1', '2', '3', '4',
              '5', '6', '7', '8', '9');
```

And I want to split this array, and add every next two items in a new array as a group, like:

```
$new_list = array(
    array('a', 'b'),
    array('c', 'd'),
    array('e', 'f'),
    array('1', '2'),
    array('3', '4'),
    array('5', '6'),
    array('7', '8'),
    array('9'), // note that this one here is alone!
);
```

But I want to do this with `foreach` or something. I only know I can divide length of my array with **2** and use `round` or `floor` PHP functions to get a whole number, but I can't figure out how to group items of this array in two items per array.

Please help me, my brain is overflowing...

Comment: `$new_list = array_chunk($list, 2);` - [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

Comment: @MarkBaker wow. Thank you for the introduction to a new function :)

Comment: @MarkBaker - Thank you Mark Baker. You're a life saver! God Blessed You and America! Thanks, seriously!

Comment: @zlomerovic - I think America has all of God's blessings that it needs, but we here in the UK need all the blessings we can get... so I'll accept yours and put it in the communal national blessing pot :)

Comment: God Blessed UK for the Harrier Jet and the SAS/SBS and Royal Marines! God Blessed Israel for PHP, Sayeret Matkal and Shayetet 13!

Answer (score 2):

```
$list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e',
    'f', '1', '2', '3', '4',
    '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];

$list2 = [];

$c = 0;
$temp_array = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < Count($list); $i++)
{
    $c++;
    array_push($temp_array, $list[$i]);
    if ($c >= 2)
    {
        array_push($list2, $temp_array);
        $temp_array = [];
        $c = 0;
    }
}

print_r($list2);

echo '<br />List2: ' . count($list2) . '<br />List: ' . count($list);
```

**EDIT:** or the solution which Mark Baker provided with the [array_chunk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) function. It's less code.